# Neo4j Rest Read timed out exception

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, timeoutexception

Using Neo4j 1.9 in REST mode and Spring Data for neo4j .. while performing load test on my app I am getting the exception below...

```
com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.URLConnectionClientHandler.handle(URLConnectionClientHandler.java:131)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.UserAgent$1.handle(UserAgent.java:68)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:616)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:559)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:72)
at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:494)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestRequest.post(ExecutingRestRequest.java:142)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:474)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.ExecutingRestAPI.query(ExecutingRestAPI.java:495)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.RestAPIFacade.query(RestAPIFacade.java:233)
at org.neo4j.rest.graphdb.query.RestCypherQueryEngine.query(RestCypherQueryEngine.java:50)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.query(SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.java:41)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.rest.SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.query(SpringRestCypherQueryEngine.java:27)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.dispatchQuery(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:108)
at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.query.GraphRepositoryQuery.execute(GraphRepositoryQuery.java:81)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:312)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy28.upsertSneakPeekRelation(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:319)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at sun.proxy.$Proxy31.upsertSneakPeekRelation(Unknown Source)
at com.haze.server.services.ProfileServices.upsertSneakPeekRelation(ProfileServices.java:53)
at com.haze.server.web.controllers.InteractionController.sneakPeak(InteractionController.java:251)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
```

I already done this load test scenario back then using Neo4j 1.8 with success.

Is it can be related to the warnings I get when starting the server..

```
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40 000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
WARNING! You are using an unsupported Java runtime. Please use JDK 6.
```

Is anything changed in the configurations between the versions? what can be the reason for that kind of exception?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any public code to reproduce this?

Comment: Any movement on this? Otherwise, follow the advise below.

Answer (score 4):

It might be because of the default read timeout of 30 seconds.
You can customize it by using the system property `org.neo4j.rest.read_timeout`.

```
java -Dorg.neo4j.rest.read_timeout=100 ...
```

will change it to 100 seconds. It would be great to be able to specify it per-query rather than globally.

Comment: This property looks like only for Rest Api. Can we set read_timeout property in cypher query with neo4j-java api, if yes then please let me know ?